# What can I do? How do i clear the front nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, laravel-8, nuxtjs3, nuxt.config.js

What can I do. how do i clear the front . I use Nuxt 3.  Server is down. Pinia 3 off. There is no such data in the database. Nuxt 3 constantly gives me a page with old data from the database, what should I do?

on the server side i did through the *config/cache.php* configuration:

Open the config/cache.php file and set the default value to array:

`'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'array')`,

and in my .env `CACHE_DRIVER to array`

*On the client side*

***My nuxt.config.ts***

```
 /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['~/assets/css/main.css'],
    modules: ['nuxt-icon',
        '@pinia/nuxt',
        '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt',
    ],
    render: {
        http2: {
            push: false,
            shouldPush: () => false,
            shouldPreload: (file, type) => false,
            shouldPrefetch: () => false,
        },
    },
    components: {
        global: true,
        dirs: ['~/components']
    },
    pinia: {
        autoImports: [
            // automatically imports `defineStore`
            'defineStore', // import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
            ['defineStore', 'definePiniaStore'], // import { defineStore as definePiniaStore } from 'pinia'
        ],
    },
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            tailwindcss: {},
            autoprefixer: {},
        },
    },
})
```

**and nuxt clean**

*so problem is*

[image: issue_1]

[image: issue_2]